# Clicar em um botão dentro do power bi com python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, pyautogui

Meus caros, preciso que meu robô clique no botão dentro do power Bi de atualizar, para ele atualizar sozinho, só falta essa parte para que ele fique 100%

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time

os.system("C:/Teste.pbix")
```

Ele já está abrindo o arquivo, quando abrir eu só preciso que ele atualize sozinho

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro para uma aplicação deste tipo uma atualização agendada do próprio Power BI.
Caso você não queira, tente utilizar o pyautogui com posicionamento de cursor para fazer a atualização ou por [Screenshot](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html). Lembrando que o posicionamento de cursor é variável de acordo com a janela ou configuração do monitor.

[Link Power BI atualização](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/atualizando-relatorios-com-bi-service?gclid=CjwKCAjwxo6IBhBKEiwAXSYBs1BDFa3AdM6SHaq-ZyBd48KKLpJQ_DvYY1aBbye53FtKQLez3ern_hoCLFUQAvD_BwE)